# isometric shape background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, background-image

I have a design in front of me that looks like this,

[image]

As you can see there is a blue square (this right half will be hidden off screen) that overlaps three disticnt sections of a webpage, and I have not how to tackle it.

The only 2 options I can are,

1) Add a portion of the purple square to each of the 3 sections to it merges together, however each section has flexible content so the changes of lining up are slim.

2) Add an absolutely positioned div and position it where i need with the square as a background image and then play with z-indexing?

Is there a simple solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
.card {
  disaply: flex;
  background: darkblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}

.card2 {
  disaply: flex;
  background: skyblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.diamond {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: purple;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-left:274px;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #ff66ff 50%, #ffe6ff 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="card">
  <h1>Item1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero suscipit quisquam, dolor laboriosam fugiat explicabo ipsam dolores.</p>
<div class="diamond"></div>
</div>

<div class="card2">
<h1>Item1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero suscipit quisquam, dolor laboriosam fugiat explicabo ipsam dolores.</p>  
</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tonytomk/pen/ExPNWjz